# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'Tensor' for tuner.lr_find()

Tags: tensorflow2.0, lightning

I'm trying to create 100 candidates learning rate using **tuner.lr_find()** between the minimum and maximum values
I tried this:

```
inputs = torch.tensor([0., 0.5, 1.])
labels = torch.tensor([0., 1., 0.])
dataset = TensorDataset(inputs, labels)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset)

model = BasicLightningTrain()
trainer = L.Trainer(max_epochs=34)

tuner = L.pytorch.tuner.Tuner(trainer)
lr_find_results = tuner.lr_find(model,
                                train_dataloaders = dataloader,
                                min_lr = 0.001,
                                max_lr=1.0,
                                early_stop_threshold=None)

new_lr = lr_find_results.suggestion()
printf(f"lr_find() suggests {new_lr:.5f} for the learning rate.")


model.learning_rate = new_lr
trainer.fit(model, train_dataloaders=dataloader)

print(model.final_bias.data)
```

but getting the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[49], line 5
      2 trainer = L.Trainer(max_epochs=34)
      4 tuner = L.pytorch.tuner.Tuner(trainer)
----> 5 lr_find_results = tuner.lr_find(model,
      6                                 train_dataloaders = dataloader,
      7                                 min_lr = 0.001,
      8                                 max_lr=1.0,
      9                                 early_stop_threshold=None)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'Tensor'
```